# Texmaker vs TeXstudio (comparison)

Tags: texmaker, texstudio, ubuntu, comparison

I would like to use either **Texmaker** or **TeXstudio** in **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**. I want to use the latest version available via some PPA (not something installed "by hand" or even compiled!). I would like to use it with texlive-extra version 2014 (also installed via some PPA). The purpose would be to write a bachelor thesis in computer science. I would start writing it by the end of august.

The question is which one is more suitable to do the job? I demand a **stable and virtually bug-free** program. I am not that much interested in the features (except for Slovak characters support). I want to use either **IEEE** or **ČSN ISO 690** citation style. I want to use [this](https://github.com/Darkless012/fithesis2c) LaTeX **style**. A year ago I had some problems using this style with Texmaker (mostly with the logo of my university) but they might have resolved already or might have been caused by the older Texlive.

According to [the comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) both have mostly the same features and are fairly up-to-date.

Comment: Have you seen our big list [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)?

Comment: Thats a nice link, thanks. Its mainly about features though and is not centered around these two IDEs. It certainly does not answer all my questions, mainly which one is more stable in real life.

Comment: People using either of these editors (or indeed any other) will probably regard them as 'stable': indeed, I'd say most of the editors I've tried out are stable enough for day-to-day use if one is happy with the features. So I'm not entirely sure this is really an answerable question.

Comment: I have read for example that TeXstudio is buggy, but that was about a year ago. Some bugs might be persistent between multiple versions. I believe there is some quantitative metric to measure bugs. Time to fix (i.e. time between releases) might also be of importance. Also does anyone have experience with the TeXlive 2014 and style and citation support in these two IDEs?

Comment: @Slazer Like all LaTeX IDEs, the editor has nothing to do with citation styles: all that IDEs might offer is the ability to pick the appropriate keys from a list in a `.bib` file. (I don't use either of the ones in question, so don't know how they stand here.)

Comment: If fact, the editor has nothing to do with with LaTeX. Any decent text editor is enough stable and bug-free. If you can write plain text without losing what you write, it's perfect. The best one is the one with which you feel most comfortable because the syntax highlighting, shortcuts, buttons for compilation and so on. But here everyone has their particular tastes. I'm afraid you'll have to compare them and decide for yourself.

Comment: BTW, there are not problem installing both and edit your work with TexMaker and the next with TeXstudio, or viceversa.

Comment: I don't think that this question is suitable for StackExchange. You have plenty of people using one or another for _all_ their LaTeX work, therefore there is no objective way of answering the question better than [the editor big list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides?lq=1).

Comment: But what about a reported number of bugs per time period and their seriousness? That is objective, isn't it? Also the support of IEEE in the IDE, response time to bugs (new version announcement) and suport for TeXlive 2014.